# Shall I host Flink jobmanager and taskmanager on the same host?

Tags: apache-flink

We are currently running Flink on a 5 nodes cluster with 5 taskmanagers. We also use 5 jobmanagers for recovery, running on the same hosts as the taskmanagers.

Last week our cluster went done because of an OutOfMemory error on a jobmanager, cascading to the 4 others.

Isolating jobmanagers and taskmanagers on different hosts would not have helped in our case, but I am wondering if host sharing is the correct architecture for high availibility.

[Edit 1] @MIkCode - OOM occured after running too much jobs on the cluster.

[Edit 2] @Dominik Wosiński - Of course not :) The first manager went down because its heap was undersized. JM 2 (on host 2) took over but failed right away as all JM have the same heap size.

Comment: What was the cause of the OOM ? Can you share some logs .

Comment: Sorry, do I understand correct that You have 1 host hosting all the instances ? Or how did exactly OOM propagate to other Jobmanagers ??